# Meteor wants MONGO_URL on startup

Tags: meteor

After then I downgrade to 0.6.4.1 version on startup I have error:

```
Error: MONGO_URL must be set in environment
```

So I try set this variable

```
root@xxx:/home/xxx/Documents/exchange# echo $MONGO_URL
mongodb://localhost:27017/exchange
```

But it doesn't help.
I try to start developer server **not** bundle.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you double-posted this in the Meteor google group as well:

> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/lAReHjJZjl0

In any case, for your reference and others, you are probably not actually on 0.6.4.1 unless you run `meteor --release 0.6.4.1`. From your other post, you are still on 0.6.5 and you need to add `standard-app-packages` for it to work properly if you were previously on 0.6.4.1. See the following:

> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1257